# Applied Combinatorics Question on arrangements

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to distribute seven distinct apples and six distinct pears to three distinct people such that each person has at least one pear?

I'm having trouble with this problem because it is not the same as the first part that asks how many ways if the apples and pears are identical.

I have tried several different approaches that have proven to be unsuccessful and I could really use some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Somebody might answer the question by suggesting one of your unsuccessful approaches.  This would be a real waste of their time, and I'm sure you don't want to do that.  So, please post details of the approaches you have tried already.

Comment: I'm sorry about that! I tried using the solution (5C2)(9C2) = 360 ways but my professor said this would be the answer if the apples and pears were identical. However, in this case the apples and pears are distinct, which makes this problem much trickier. I'm confused now because I am only able to solve this problem if they are identical I'm unsure how to go about this because they are distinct. Thanks for your comment, I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: This is a really good question and I am stumped

Answer (score 0):

The total number of ways to distribute six different pears to three people is $3^6$.  Using inclusion/exclusion, the number of ways to do it in which no person remains pearless is
$$3^6-3\times2^6+3\times1^6\ .$$
Distributing seven different apples too makes the total number of ways to do it
$$3^7(3^6-3\times2^6+3)\ .$$